# Twitter - how to get user's timeline

Tags: xcode, post, twitter, timeline

My app, in one of its parts, should reproduce the same behaviour as a web page, where you can find a section with a table of Twitter posts, I guess they are a user's timeline. I took a look at Twitter api's and I found a call which could return it, but, If I got it right, you are supposed to be authenticated with that user credentials. Is there a way to achieve it without being that user (thus without using that user's credentials)? If not we have to assume that web plugins have more flexibility than queries which return xml, or json? Which kind of approach fits best, considering the app needs to support iOS from 4.3 to 6.x? Does Twitter+Oauth provide more flexibility than direct Twitter api calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, if you are looking to just display user's feed you can do it as simple as:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=reMakeIn&count=200

Where you change the screen_name to the desired user that you want to show the feeds for.
No need what so ever to use authentication for this.

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but I use this approach to show random user's tweet feed.

Comment: good point, but that is rss, and I need something like xml or json, I guess, to build custom graphics upon it

Comment: glad i could help, in my hurry to answer I missed your need for an xml or json  version. :)