# how to get my twitter timeline entries

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have tried [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442128/twitter-how-to-get-users-timeline).

But requesting this:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=monyetbego
```

keep giving me `Bad Authentication data`.

I don't know exactly how to get authenticated.

Comment: Add the **language** that you are using as a tag to better help us to help you.

Comment: You have to use some server side library for getting authentication of user to get users timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register an application through [Twitter's developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/). Once your application is approved you will be given a set of Oauth keys, which you can use within an API request to receive a response. Note that in API V1.1, you can no longer submit unauthenticated requests (i.e. send requests through a unauthenticated URL like the one you posted).

For example, once you have your authentication information, you can use curl to submit a show_timeline request (see your Application's OAuth tool on the Twitter Dev website for parameters specific to your authentication information):

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/user_timeline.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_nonce="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_signature_method="XXXX-XXXXX", 
oauth_timestamp="XXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_token="XXXXXXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate a web app that is not accessible from the internet? But the web app can access the internet.

Comment: I have found the [twitter4j](twitter4j.org) website. The explanation inside it made me understand. Now I can get user_timeline and show it on the web app.